# External mic not working Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: microphone

I am dual boot with WinXP. For the last week I've tried to get my headset microphone working so I can make phone calls from gmail. When the microphone did not work there and then didn't work in Ubuntu I decided to start with the OS and that would probably take care of the issue with gmail. When I try to use my headset in Ubuntu I get sound but the mic does not function. When I boot into WinXP the opposite happens where the mic works but sound does not. Going back to Ubuntu I access the Sound Settings, Input and when I speak into the mic the level indicator does not move. I have tried various forum suggestions from adding lines to   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf   file to making adjustments to alsamixer and nothing works. It's worth noting that the mic did work at some point years ago and I assume something has changed with 12.04 as I regularly update it. Thanks in advance for any input.

Update:  Just followed the mic section at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
and it works.